# How can I pass large arrays between numpy and R?

Tags: python, r, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass large arrays between numpy and R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654807/how-can-i-pass-large-arrays-between-numpy-and-r)

I'm using python and numpy/scipy to do regex and stemming for a text processing application. But I want to use some of R's statistical packages as well.

What's the best way to pass the data from python to R?  (And back?)

Also, I need to backup the array to disk at some point, so I'm open to saving from python and loading th R if that's the best solution.  The matrices are pretty big (e.g. 100,000 x 10,000), so using sparse matrices might also be nice.

Note: This is [cross-posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9529/how-can-i-pass-large-arrays-between-numpy-and-r) at crossvalidated.  Didn't know which community was the right place to post.