# How can I pass large arrays between numpy and R?

Tags: python, r, numpy, matrix

I'm using python and numpy/scipy to do regex and stemming for a text processing application. But I want to use some of R's statistical packages as well.

What's the best way to pass the data from python to R?  (And back?)

Also, I need to backup the array to disk at some point, so I'm open to saving from python and loading th R if that's the best solution.  The matrices are pretty big (e.g. 100,000 x 10,000), so using sparse matrices might also be nice.

Apologies if this is a repost.  I haven't been able to find anything that puts all these pieces together.

Comment: The problem is that cross-posting over different SEs is not the way to do (apart from the fact that it's not encouraged). One purpose of SE is to create a lasting record of great solutions to specific questions, that can be accessed from e.g. googling or referring sites. By duplicating your question, you raise the possibility of getting different good answers from different sites, which is fair good but which one would you accept in the end? Moreover, as you didn't notify stats.SE that this was cross-posted from SO, it was simply migrated. Now, mods have to merge them both.

Comment: Merged. As chl said, please don't post the same question on multiple sites in the future.

Comment: My mistake.  I asked this question on crossvalidated first, and was told it would work better here.  After I posted here, the other post was also migrated.  For future reference, how could I move the question myself?  Sometimes it's hard to decide which community is better suited to answering a given question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Have you already looked into [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/)? It's a python interface to R. I guess that would spare you the data handling.
- To backup your NumPy arrays you can use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). As it seems to create a lot of overhead when saving huge data, NumPy arrays are best saved using the HDF standard. Here's a article covering that: http://www.shocksolution.com/2010/01/10/storing-large-numpy-arrays-on-disk-python-pickle-vs-hdf5adsf/

Comment: "NumPy arrays are best saved using the HDF standard"... HDF is great, but it's overkill if you just need to save the array to disk efficiently. For simple, efficient saving and loading of numpy arrays, just use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load`. That's what they're meant for, and they avoid the (huge) overhead incurred when pickling numpy arrays.  Of course, if you want to load the array from another language, HDF is probably a good route.

Comment: @Joe Kington: +1 Good Point! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use Rpy, http://rpy.sourceforge.net/, to call R from Python.

The caveat is that both R and Python versions need to be exactly the one for which the Rpy binary has been built. You thus need to be careful with the installation.

Comment: I got one down vote for this answer. Why? Because of my comment on the versions? Well, I believe that it's factually true, and it's useful to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on "large data" between shared between R and Python, but I have had a much easier time working with [pyRserve](http://packages.python.org/pyRserve/intro.html) than RPy or RPy2.

That being said, I am curious about the text processing you are doing? Python obviously has a lot to offer on the text processing side, but statistically there is a lot too in packages like [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) and the [Pattern package from CLiPS](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern). Are you just more comfortable doing stats in R, or is there something specific missing in Python?

Comment: >Are you just more comfortable doing stats in R, or is there something specific missing in Python?< Both.  I'm going to be building my own estimators, which I expect to be much easier in R.